# How do I upload my music into iCloud

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, data-synchronization

I have a few spiritual yoga and madras related mp3s on my MacBook's iTunes that I would like to listen to on my iPhone.

How can I sync it through iCloud? Normal good old iTunes library sync does not work anymore as I experienced.

Comment: Hi. Can you please provide a bit more information? From what you say it appears that you cannot sync your files between your Mac and iPhone over USB, so you want to use iCloud. Is that right? Apple provides two main options to sync music via iCloud. They are Apple Music and iTunes Match. The differences between them are explained on this Apple Support page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204962.

Comment: It is not usb it is over wifi.